# how to set up MQ to allow three services communicate with each other using MQ Explorer

Tags: java, c++, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to simulate a workflow where i have three MQ servers, A, B and C.

What i want to do is to have both A and C services send messages to B and B equally to be able to send messages to both A and C.

A -----> B (B receives messages from A)
C -----> B (B receives messages from C)

B -----> A (B sends messages to A) 
B -----> C (B sends messages to C)

What is the best or most straight forward way to set this up using the explorer MQ GUI? All three services will be running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use MQ Explorer to do the setup (too easy to make a mistake) but rather use MQSC commands.

First do the A & B queue manager setup then do the B & C queue manager setup.

Here's an MQ blog posting on how to do a complete setup between 2 queue managers:
http://www.capitalware.biz/rl_blog/?p=509

Remember, if you are running 3 queue managers on the same server then each queue manager (listener) will need its own port number.  i.e. A uses 1414, B uses 1415, C uses 1416.